Visual Studio Apple Account Login or API Key Information?
I am transitioning to a new machine, both are running Visual Studio 2022 17.  On my old machine when I go into Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple Accounts and click Add then choose Enterprise Account I get a prompt to enter my Apple ID credentials:

When I do the same thing on my new machine I get a much different prompt, this one is requiring Enterprise Program API Key information:

Is this a change in Visual Studio, or do I have something configured incorrectly on my new machine?  Is it possible to get the new machine to add the Apple account using the Apple ID Credentials?

Which version of VS2022 are you using? I am experiencing the same problem on a machine where I installed version 17.12.3. I do not have this problem on my other machines where 17.10.4 is installed. You can look up your version using the menu items "Help-About Microsoft Visual Studio".

My old machine has 17.10.?, my new machine has 17.12.1
